# Windows update is not installing itself

Tags: windows, updates

I have this kind of problem: once upon a time my Windows 7 Home premium downloaded, probably bad, update and it didn't install itself for the first time. And now every time I shut down my computer is still tries to install itself again and again. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2509997) should help you with your problem.